# How find this integral $I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin^2{\left(a(x-y)+b(x^2-y^2)\right)}}{(x-y)^2}dxdy$

Tags: integration

let $a,b$ is constant real numbers,and $a,b\neq 0$,Find the integral
$$I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\sin^2{\left(a(x-y)+b(x^2-y^2)\right)}}{(x-y)^2}dxdy$$

maybe I want let
$$x-y=u,x+y=v\Longrightarrow x=\dfrac{u+v}{2},y=\dfrac{u-v}{2}$$
$$|J|=\left|\begin{vmatrix}
\dfrac{1}{2}&\dfrac{1}{2}\\
\dfrac{1}{2}&-\dfrac{1}{2}
\end{vmatrix}\right|=|-\dfrac{1}{2}|=\dfrac{1}{2}$$
then
$$I(a,b)=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\int_{0}^{1}\int_{-u}^{u}\dfrac{\sin^2{(au+buv)}}{u^2}dvdu+\int_{1}^{2}\int_{u-2}^{2-u}\dfrac{\sin^2{(au+buv)}}{u^2}dvdu\right)$$

Then I can't.Thank you

Comment: What makes you believe that this integral has a simple, closed solution?